# Kentico cms:FormSubmit localization and layout html

Tags: kentico

I've created a Form, with the following layout:

```html
<fieldset class="form-group subject">
  <legend>Subject</legend>
  <cms:FormLabel runat="server" ID="lTextBoxControl" Field="TextBoxControl" /><cms:FormErrorLabel runat="server" ID="eTextBoxControl" Field="TextBoxControl" />
  <cms:FormControl runat="server" ID="iTextBoxControl" Field="TextBoxControl" FormControlName="TextBoxControl" CssClass="" />
  

</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group message">
  <legend>Message</legend>
  <cms:FormLabel runat="server" ID="labelMessage" Field="TextAreaControl" /><cms:FormErrorLabel runat="server" ID="messageError" Field="TextAreaControl" />  
  <cms:FormControl runat="server" ID="iTextAreaControl" Field="TextAreaControl" FormControlName="TextAreaControl" CssClass="" />
</fieldset>
<cms:FormSubmit runat="server" ID="fSubmit"  />
```

I have a localization string for the button label, but can't get that work. Also, when this rendors, it's wrapped in a TABLE tag which is a big issue too.

I can't see anything in the V9 documentation for this control either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more digging and i came up with this : http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/custom-submit-button-text

Forms > General > Submit Button Text

I then used my localization string.